# Typescript Export all types/classes from multiple d.ts files under one namespace

Tags: typescript

I have been working with typescript and protobuf. Basically after running the proto compiler with the ts-protoc-gen plugin I get several files.

- a.d.ts
- a.js
- b.d.ts
- b.js

These files contain the typescript types/classes generated from the proto message. The problem is several files can span the same namespace, so I would like to import all the types/classes from the relevant files and export them all under the same namespace.

The research I've done up to this point makes it sound like this would work:

```
import * as A from "../a";
import * as B from "../b";

export namespace myNamespace {
    export import a = A;
    export import b = B;
}
```

But I would like to export them all under `myNamespace` and not under myNamespace.a and myNamespace.b. I've tried using the spread operator but it seems to skip the types. Is there a way to aggregate everything and export under a single name?